# How can I solve for mod to get a value?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I want to solve the following part involving mod:

```
1 = -5(19) (mod 96)
```

Apparently, this mod in brackets `(mod 96)` here is different from the mod that I know e.g. its not the remainder value that you get by dividing.

What of kind of mod is it and how can I solve it step by step to get the result which is 77?

**Update:**

Okay, so I am trying to find what's 5 inverse mod 96.

By following euclidean algorithm approach here's what I am doing:

**Step1:** Find GCD of 5 and 96

```
96 = 5(19) + 1
```

which becomes `1 = 96-5(19)` when expresses in `1` term

**Step 2:** Take mod (96) both sides

So I will have left:

```
1 = -5(19) (mod 96)
```

That's from where I need to solve it to get 5 inverse (mod 96).

Comment: Hard to follow your question. Sorry. What do you mean to get an answer 77?

Comment: What are you solving for?

Comment: It's the last steps of euclidean algorithm to find 5 inverse (mod 96).

Comment: "$1\equiv -5\cdot19\pmod{96}$" is not something it makes sense to _solve_, or something that gives a _result_. It is just a true statement of fact: the numbers $1$ and $-5\times 19$ (which is $-95$) differ by a multiple of $96$. If you have found it in a context where someone continues "... therefore the result is 77", then you haven't quoted enough of the context to let us see what that someone is _actually_ doing -- the number $77$ has nothing in particular to do with the fact that $1\equiv -5\cdot19\pmod{96}$.

Comment: @Henning Makholm Sorry. So I rather delete my answer. But honestly I based my answer to his comment  which says he want to find the multiplicative of $5$ in mod 96.

Comment: (Note: ΘΣΦ GenSan, in a now deleted answer, pointed out that $-19\equiv 77\pmod{96}$, which may be a piece in the puzzle of what it is actually going on in the text the OP is quoting from).

Comment: @Henning Makholm I'm reading too fast, not even getting the idea of OP' question. Sorry.

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan: I wasn't calling for you to delete your answer (and didn't even downvote); I simply wasn't sure what you were on about.

Comment: Please see the updated question.

Comment: @user963241: Thank you; now it's much clearer what your problem is.

Comment: So based on the updated question, we are at $$1\equiv (-19)5\pmod{96}.$$Equivalently, this means that $$5(-19)\equiv 1\pmod{96}.$$ This meas that any $x$ such that $x\equiv -19\pmod{96}$ is the inverse of $5$. One of those $x$ is $77$.

Comment: @Henning Makholm Am I getting right with my answer above? That is what I meant in my deleted answer.

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan: Yes, that now matches my understanding of the question too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $$ a\equiv b \pmod n $$
means that $a$ and $b$ are in the same *residue class* modulo $n$. If you're more used to $\bmod$ as a binary operator, this is the same as saying
$$ a\bmod n = b\bmod n$$
though we have to remember that the $\bmod$ here is one that always produces a result in $[0,n)$ even for a negative argument, such that, as will be relevant here, $(-19)\bmod 96 = 77$.

---

When you're being asked to find a multiplicative inverse of $5$ modulo $96$, what this *means* is to find an $x$ such that
$$\tag1 5x\equiv 1 \pmod{96} $$
Through the previous steps of the solution you have reached the knowledge that
$$\tag2 1 \equiv -5 \cdot 19 \pmod{96} $$
which is *almost* the same as what you're looking for, except that

1. The $1$ is on the other side -- but that doesn't matter, because the definition of $\equiv$ is clearly symmetric in $a$ and $b$.
2. There is a $-5$ instead of a $5$ in $\text{(2)}$. But we can get a $5$ instead by rembering (basic aritmetic) that $(-5)\cdot 19 = 5\cdot(-19)$.

So, since we know $\text{(2)}$ is true, we also know
$$\tag3 5\cdot(-19) \equiv 1 \pmod{96} $$
which tells us that $-19$ is a solution for $x$ in $\text{(1)}$.

All that is left to do is find the *canonical* representive of the residue class that contains $-19$, by adding or subtracting some multiple of $96$ to get it into the range $[0,96)$:
$$ -19 \bmod 96 = 77 $$
In other words, since changing one factor by a multiple of $n$ doesn't change the residue modulo $n$, we also know that
$$ 5\cdot 77 \equiv 1 \pmod{96}$$
which says that $5$ and $77$ are multiplicative inverses modulo $96$.

Comment: I haven't done a division with negatives like this before. So, is this how: http://i66.tinypic.com/20ptz5v.gif I will divide the -19 and 96 to get mod 77?

Comment: @user963241: An ordinary rational division _without_ remainder gives $(-19)\div 96 = -0\frac{19}{96}$. To find the modulus, round the quotient _down_ (towards minus infinity) to $-1$, multiply by $96$ and subtract this from $-19$: $$ -19 - (-1 \cdot 96) = 77 $$ This procedure works uniformly both for positive and negative dividends. (Only the _shortcut_ of reading the remainder directly off from the long division doesn't).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the update of your post, you are looking for $x$ for which 
$$5x\equiv 1\pmod{96}.$$
This $x$ is called the multiplicative inverse of $5$ in mod $96$. Now, we have
$$1\equiv (-19)5\pmod{96}$$ which means that $$5(-19)\equiv 1\pmod{96}.$$ This means any $x$ such that $$x\equiv -19\pmod{96}$$ is the inverse of $5$ in mod $96$.  Observe that $$-19\equiv 77\pmod{96}.$$  Hence, all solutions of $x$ are given by$$x\equiv 77\pmod{96}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$1 \equiv -5(19) \mod 96$ is equivalent to $1 \equiv -95 \mod 96$ by multiplying out the brackets.

For your question it's equivalent to going round a clock with $96$ hours on it - each time you reach $96$th hour it goes back to $0$ and starts again.

This can also be extended to negative numbers, and adding multiples of $96$. Hence:

$$1 \equiv -5(19) \mod 96 \equiv 1 \mod 96$$